# Solving an "ClassNotFoundException" on Linux

Tags: java, linux, classnotfoundexception

I've developed a java app with Eclipse on Windows 7 with the JDK v6. The app is 100% run-able on windows but when I tried to launch it on Ubuntu I got this trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask
    at com.inserm.controllers.PDFReader.<clinit>(PDFReader.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 1 more
Could not find the main class: com.inserm.controllers.PDFReader. Program will exit.
```

using the command line (I'm launching it from the folder where my jar is)

```
java -jar Reader.jar
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I bet the used java version is to old, what does `java -version` print?

Comment: ForkJoinTask exists since JDK 7.

Comment: ForkJoinTask is available since jdk 7, so you are missing something. Probably your JDK on Windows is not the 6

Comment: What's the code in this line: com.inserm.controllers.PDFReader.<clinit>(PDFReader.java:17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your jdk to the latest version (min 1.7).

To do this try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

Comment: As it's a restricted computer, I can't.
But as my target JRE is 1.6, what's the point of updating to 1.7?

Comment: @Antoine ForkJoinTask does **not** exist in a JRE 1.6

Comment: You don't need to install Java globally, use your home directory. - You need 1.7 because the missing class isn't in 1.6 and earlier.

Comment: Yes... if you dont have admin permission use your home folder to "install" jdk 1.7